# Swift - App getting crashed in IOS 8.4 on launch with error _NSURLSessionTaskPriorityDefault

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, ios8, ios-simulator

App is getting crashed on launch, with error log

> dyld: Symbol not found: _NSURLSessionTaskPriorityDefault   Referenced
>   from:
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/E302B99F-08D3-45C0-A8ED-F500052FF375/AppName.app/AppName
>   Expected in:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation  in
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/E302B99F-08D3-45C0-A8ED-F500052FF375/AppName.app/AppName

IOS Target Version : 8.0
Swift : version 2.2

Device: Iphone 6
Device Version 8.4

Comment: I am also facing same problem. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

1. Make sure that you have linked your project with Foundation.framework and CFNetwork.framework
2. Make sure the Foundation framework include is before CFNetwork.
3. If you already have this configuration in your project then once un-link these frameworks, clean your project and link them again.

My project has been working well after this, hope yours does as well.