# App Compiled in Xcode 9 crashes on startup for iOS9 and iOS10 - dyld: Symbol not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire, xcode9

My app worked fine on all iOS version when compiled with XCode8. Now, when compiled with Xcode 9, it runs fine on iOS11 devices, but it crashes for simulator and devices running iOS10 and iOS9. I get below message in the console:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURLSessionStreamTask
Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3BE9A47-374A-4BEA-AC7F-A01F4B0FD87F/MyApp.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
in /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3BE9A47-374A-4BEA-AC7F-A01F4B0FD87F/MyApp.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
```

As you can see I'm using Alamofire. The development target of my app is 9.3 and the dev target of Alamofire is also 9.3. The BaseSDK is iOS11 (because it's Xcode 9).

After doing some research I don't believe this is an Alamofire issue, but rather a Xcode issue. These are some similar issues I found, but having tried all offered solutions (including the standard clean / clean build folder / delete derived data), none of them seem to work:

- https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2142
- https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/68430
- [Swift - App getting crashed in IOS 8.4 on launch with error _NSURLSessionTaskPriorityDefault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225871/swift-app-getting-crashed-in-ios-8-4-on-launch-with-error-nsurlsessiontaskpri)

Does anyone have a solution for this, other then rolling back to Xcode 8?

Comment: @AlekseyKozhevnikov Tried fresh installs on devices and sims. No luck. Same message in console.

Comment: Strange. The `NSURLSessionStreamTask` class has been in the Foundation framework since iOS 9.

Comment: If it matters: I added Alamofire manually following the installation instructions. This has worked fine for Xcode8.

Comment: Do you use pods in your project? Why don't you add Alamofire as pod automatically?

Comment: Because Alamofire requires use_frameworks and I have some objective_c pods in there which don't work well with that.

Answer (score 5):

Found the solution. It was similar to other posts on the same topic, but with a twist. This is how I got it working:

- Add Foundation.framework to Linked Frameworks and Libraries of **the Alamofire iOS target** (so not your project's target)
- Make it **optional**. (I tried required, but that didn't work).

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the issue. In our Podfile we had this set:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.3'
    end
  end
end
```

When I remove that, the crash goes away.

Changing Foundation to optional like the other post suggested also resolved the issue, but didn't work with our build process since running pod install again would overwrite the change and make it required again.